# Yahoo - OAuth2 - what is Error 95037?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am trying to implement oauth2 for yahoo (target is yahoo's contact api). See here: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#implicit-grant-flow-for-client-side-apps

However, I get the following error:

> Oops. Yahoo is unable to process your request.
>   We recommend that you contact the owner of the application or web site to resolve this issue. [95037]

How to get this resolved? It comes with I use `response_type=token` (which is needed for Implicit Grant Flow), but works fine for `response_type=code`

[EDIT]
The request to yahoo (urldecoded):

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&response_type=token&redirect_uri=[PATH]&display=popup&scope=&state={"client_id":"[CLIENT_ID]","network":"yahoo","display":"popup","callback":"_hellojs_23g8z6wk","state":"","redirect_uri":"[PATH]","scope":"friends,basic"}
```

**[UPDATE]**
After following the recommendations from `HansZ.`, I was able to resolve it.

Now the issue has come back without changing any code. Basically, it only works when I am logged in with the Yahoo ID that I used to setup the App at Yahoo.

Otherwise, sometimes it goes in loops and chrome says

> This webpage has a redirect loop`

rest of the time it gives the error again.

Comment: Can you show the exact authorization request that you send to yahoo?

Comment: You can pass values to `state` using the URL format too, like `param1=value1&param2=value2`, just with a URL escape, to make them no break the entire request.

Comment: @HansZ. see update.. now how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `state` is the problem. I can reproduce the problem by including your URL-encoded state in the authorization request for my Yahoo client. The problem is the length of the state or the total URL. You may revert to using a cookie for maintaining that state and send only the (much shorter) cookie name as the `state` parameter.

Comment: Ur right, but I am trying to implement it on Hello.js and it doesnt work if I dont pass the `state`.. :(

Comment: You could also try and store the state somewhere else (by calling a remote API on some "storage" service) and send the reference to that?